# Why std::random_shuffle creates empty value in std::vector?

Tags: c++, vector

I would like to shuffle a vector of char but I noticed it created empty values. Here is part of the code :

```
vector<char> letters_num;
vector<char> shuffle_letters_num;

char default_letters_num[88] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k',
'l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z',
'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O',
'P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z',
'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'
};

letters_num.insert(letters_num.begin(),default_letters_num,default_letters_num+88);

shuffle_letters_num=letters_num;
random_shuffle(shuffle_letters_num.begin(),shuffle_letters_num.end());
```

*shuffle_letters_num* is correcly shuffled but the size of shuffle_letters_num is greater than *letters_num*.

So when I try something like this, the content of iterator can be empty :

```
for(int i = 0; i < size_string; ++i) {
    it=find(shuffle_letters_num.begin(),shuffle_letters_num.end(),string[i]);

    if(it==shuffle_letters_num.end())
    {
        return "";
    }

    if(it==shuffle_letters_num.begin())
    {
        result+=shuffle_letters_num.at(shuffle_letters_num.size()-1);
    }
    else
    {
        it--;
        result += *it;
    }
}
```

How shuffle a vector proprely without generate empty values ?

Comment: FYI, this overload of `std::random_shuffle` will be removed in C++17. It's highly recommended to use `std::shuffle` instead.

Comment: There are 26 uppercase letters, 26 lowercase letters, and 88-26-26=36 digits. Am I right?

Comment: ... Well yes, I am stupid, I forgot to update the size of the array after remove some char. Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't have used hardcoded sizes in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest way is probably to just initialize the vector directly:

```
vector<char> letters_num {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k',
    'l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z',
    'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O',
    'P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z',
    '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'
};

vector<char> shuffle_letters_num {letters_num};

random_shuffle(shuffle_letters_num.begin(),shuffle_letters_num.end());
```

If you're stuck with an older compiler that doesn't support that, you'd want to let the compiler compute the size for you:

```
char default_letters_num[] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k',
'l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z',
'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O',
'P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z',
'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'
};
```

...and to go with that, a couple of function templates to find the beginning and end of the array correctly:

```
template <class T, size_t N>
T *begin(T (&array)[N]) {
    return array;
}

template <class T, size_t N>
T *end(T (&array)[N]) { 
    return array + N;
}
```

Using these, initializing the vector from the array could look something like this:

```
vector<char> shuffle_letters_num (begin(letters_num), end(letters(num));
```

Either way, we've eliminated the error-prone hand counting of the items in the array, and let the compiler do that for us (it's definitely better at it than I've ever even hoped to be).

Answer (score 4):

```
char default_letters_num[88]
```

Well, you define an array of 88 chars, but you only provide 26 + 26 + 10 = 62 initializers, so the last 88 - 62 = 16 characters have the value zero.

Just replace both occurrences of 88 with 62 and everything should work as expected.

Comment: The OP also needs to change `letters_num.insert(letters_num.begin(),default_letters_num,default_letters_num+88);`

Comment: Or better yet initialize the vector directly, should work with the initializer_list overload.

Comment: Or use `char default_num_letters[] = { ::: ]:` and `sizeof` instead of hardocoding the size...